# cannot run the sklearn machine learning model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, openai-gym

I am trying to use the sklearn to build a machine learning model for the lunar lander. I use Grid search to tune the model and use joblib to persist the model.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oy6W6.png)
here is the code:

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
joblib.dump(my_tuned_model, 'player_state.pkl')
```

and then I copy the player_state.pkl into the folder of lunar lander. below is the code of lunar_lander

```
import sys, math
import numpy as np
from sklearn.externals import joblib

import cv2

# MOD Extra imports for image handling
from PIL import Image
import os
import time
import datetime
import keras

import Box2D
from Box2D.b2 import (edgeShape, circleShape, fixtureDef, polygonShape, revoluteJointDef, contactListener)

import gym
from gym import spaces
from gym.utils import seeding

# Rocket trajectory optimization is a classic topic in Optimal Control.
#
# According to Pontryagin's maximum principle it's optimal to fire engine full throttle or
# turn it off. That's the reason this environment is OK to have discreet actions (engine on or off).
#
# Landing pad is always at coordinates (0,0). Coordinates are the first two numbers in state vector.
# Reward for moving from the top of the screen to landing pad and zero speed is about 100..140 points.
# If lander moves away from landing pad it loses reward back. Episode finishes if the lander crashes or
# comes to rest, receiving additional -100 or +100 points. Each leg ground contact is +10. Firing main
# engine is -0.3 points each frame. Solved is 200 points.
#
# Landing outside landing pad is possible. Fuel is infinite, so an agent can learn to fly and then land
# on its first attempt. Please see source code for details.
#
# Too see heuristic landing, run:
#
# python gym/envs/box2d/lunar_lander_mod.py
#
# To play yourself, run:
#
# python examples/agents/keyboard_agent.py LunarLander-v0
#
# Created by Oleg Klimov. Licensed on the same terms as the rest of OpenAI Gym.

FPS = 50
SCALE = 30.0  # affects how fast-paced the game is, forces should be adjusted as well

MAIN_ENGINE_POWER = 13.0
SIDE_ENGINE_POWER = 0.6

INITIAL_RANDOM = 1000.0  # Set 1500 to make game harder

LANDER_POLY = [
    (-14, +17), (-17, 0), (-17, -10),
    (+17, -10), (+17, 0), (+14, +17)
]
LEG_AWAY = 20
LEG_DOWN = 18
LEG_W, LEG_H = 2, 8
LEG_SPRING_TORQUE = 40

SIDE_ENGINE_HEIGHT = 14.0
SIDE_ENGINE_AWAY = 12.0

VIEWPORT_W = 600
VIEWPORT_H = 400


class ContactDetector(contactListener):
    def __init__(self, env):
        contactListener.__init__(self)
        self.env = env

    def BeginContact(self, contact):
        if self.env.lander == contact.fixtureA.body or self.env.lander == contact.fixtureB.body:
            self.env.game_over = True
        for i in range(2):
            if self.env.legs[i] in [contact.fixtureA.body, contact.fixtureB.body]:
                self.env.legs[i].ground_contact = True

    def EndContact(self, contact):
        for i in range(2):
            if self.env.legs[i] in [contact.fixtureA.body, contact.fixtureB.body]:
                self.env.legs[i].ground_contact = False


class LunarLander(gym.Env):
    metadata = {
        'render.modes': ['human', 'rgb_array'],
        'video.frames_per_second': FPS
    }

    continuous = False

    def __init__(self):
        self.seed()
        self.viewer = None

        self.world = Box2D.b2World()
        self.moon = None
        self.lander = None
        self.particles = []

        self.prev_reward = None

        high = np.array([np.inf] * 8)  # useful range is -1 .. +1, but spikes can be higher
        self.observation_space = spaces.Box(-high, high)

        if self.continuous:
            # Action is two floats [main engine, left-right engines].
            # Main engine: -1..0 off, 0..+1 throttle from 50% to 100% power. Engine can't work with less than 50% power.
            # Left-right:  -1.0..-0.5 fire left engine, +0.5..+1.0 fire right engine, -0.5..0.5 off
            self.action_space = spaces.Box(-1, +1, (2,))
        else:
            # Nop, fire left engine, main engine, right engine
            self.action_space = spaces.Discrete(4)

        self.reset()

    def seed(self, seed=None):
        self.np_random, seed = seeding.np_random(seed)
        return [seed]

    def _destroy(self):
        if not self.moon: return
        self.world.contactListener = None
        self._clean_particles(True)
        self.world.DestroyBody(self.moon)
        self.moon = None
        self.world.DestroyBody(self.lander)
        self.lander = None
        self.world.DestroyBody(self.legs[0])
        self.world.DestroyBody(self.legs[1])

    def reset(self):
        self._destroy()
        self.world.contactListener_keepref = ContactDetector(self)
        self.world.contactListener = self.world.contactListener_keepref
        self.game_over = False
        self.prev_shaping = None

        W = VIEWPORT_W / SCALE
        H = VIEWPORT_H / SCALE

        # terrain
        CHUNKS = 11
        height = self.np_random.uniform(0, H / 2, size=(CHUNKS + 1,))
        chunk_x = [W / (CHUNKS - 1) * i for i in range(CHUNKS)]
        self.helipad_x1 = chunk_x[CHUNKS // 2 - 1]
        self.helipad_x2 = chunk_x[CHUNKS // 2 + 1]
        self.helipad_y = H / 4
        height[CHUNKS // 2 - 2] = self.helipad_y
        height[CHUNKS // 2 - 1] = self.helipad_y
        height[CHUNKS // 2 + 0] = self.helipad_y
        height[CHUNKS // 2 + 1] = self.helipad_y
        height[CHUNKS // 2 + 2] = self.helipad_y
        smooth_y = [0.33 * (height[i - 1] + height[i + 0] + height[i + 1]) for i in range(CHUNKS)]

        self.moon = self.world.CreateStaticBody(shapes=edgeShape(vertices=[(0, 0), (W, 0)]))
        self.sky_polys = []
        for i in range(CHUNKS - 1):
            p1 = (chunk_x[i], smooth_y[i])
            p2 = (chunk_x[i + 1], smooth_y[i + 1])
            self.moon.CreateEdgeFixture(
                vertices=[p1, p2],
                density=0,
                friction=0.1)
            self.sky_polys.append([p1, p2, (p2[0], H), (p1[0], H)])

        self.moon.color1 = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        self.moon.color2 = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)

        initial_y = VIEWPORT_H / SCALE
        self.lander = self.world.CreateDynamicBody(
            position=(VIEWPORT_W / SCALE / 2, initial_y),
            angle=0.0,
            fixtures=fixtureDef(
                shape=polygonShape(vertices=[(x / SCALE, y / SCALE) for x, y in LANDER_POLY]),
                density=5.0,
                friction=0.1,
                categoryBits=0x0010,
                maskBits=0x001,  # collide only with ground
                restitution=0.0)  # 0.99 bouncy
        )
        self.lander.color1 = (0.5, 0.4, 0.9)
        self.lander.color2 = (0.3, 0.3, 0.5)
        self.lander.ApplyForceToCenter((
            self.np_random.uniform(-INITIAL_RANDOM, INITIAL_RANDOM),
            self.np_random.uniform(-INITIAL_RANDOM, INITIAL_RANDOM)
        ), True)

        self.legs = []
        for i in [-1, +1]:
            leg = self.world.CreateDynamicBody(
                position=(VIEWPORT_W / SCALE / 2 - i * LEG_AWAY / SCALE, initial_y),
                angle=(i * 0.05),
                fixtures=fixtureDef(
                    shape=polygonShape(box=(LEG_W / SCALE, LEG_H / SCALE)),
                    density=1.0,
                    restitution=0.0,
                    categoryBits=0x0020,
                    maskBits=0x001)
            )
            leg.ground_contact = False
            leg.color1 = (0.5, 0.4, 0.9)
            leg.color2 = (0.3, 0.3, 0.5)
            rjd = revoluteJointDef(
                bodyA=self.lander,
                bodyB=leg,
                localAnchorA=(0, 0),
                localAnchorB=(i * LEG_AWAY / SCALE, LEG_DOWN / SCALE),
                enableMotor=True,
                enableLimit=True,
                maxMotorTorque=LEG_SPRING_TORQUE,
                motorSpeed=+0.3 * i  # low enough not to jump back into the sky
            )
            if i == -1:
                rjd.lowerAngle = +0.9 - 0.5  # Yes, the most esoteric numbers here, angles legs have freedom to travel within
                rjd.upperAngle = +0.9
            else:
                rjd.lowerAngle = -0.9
                rjd.upperAngle = -0.9 + 0.5
            leg.joint = self.world.CreateJoint(rjd)
            self.legs.append(leg)

        self.drawlist = [self.lander] + self.legs

        return self.step(np.array([0, 0]) if self.continuous else 0)[0]

    def _create_particle(self, mass, x, y, ttl):
        p = self.world.CreateDynamicBody(
            position=(x, y),
            angle=0.0,
            fixtures=fixtureDef(
                shape=circleShape(radius=2 / SCALE, pos=(0, 0)),
                density=mass,
                friction=0.1,
                categoryBits=0x0100,
                maskBits=0x001,  # collide only with ground
                restitution=0.3)
        )
        p.ttl = ttl
        self.particles.append(p)
        self._clean_particles(False)
        return p

    def _clean_particles(self, all):
        while self.particles and (all or self.particles[0].ttl < 0):
            self.world.DestroyBody(self.particles.pop(0))

    def step(self, action):
        assert self.action_space.contains(action), "%r (%s) invalid " % (action, type(action))

        # Engines
        tip = (math.sin(self.lander.angle), math.cos(self.lander.angle))
        side = (-tip[1], tip[0]);
        dispersion = [self.np_random.uniform(-1.0, +1.0) / SCALE for _ in range(2)]

        m_power = 0.0
        if (self.continuous and action[0] > 0.0) or (not self.continuous and action == 2):
            # Main engine
            if self.continuous:
                m_power = (np.clip(action[0], 0.0, 1.0) + 1.0) * 0.5  # 0.5..1.0
                assert m_power >= 0.5 and m_power <= 1.0
            else:
                m_power = 1.0
            ox = tip[0] * (4 / SCALE + 2 * dispersion[0]) + side[0] * dispersion[
                1]  # 4 is move a bit downwards, +-2 for randomness
            oy = -tip[1] * (4 / SCALE + 2 * dispersion[0]) - side[1] * dispersion[1]
            impulse_pos = (self.lander.position[0] + ox, self.lander.position[1] + oy)
            p = self._create_particle(3.5, impulse_pos[0], impulse_pos[1],
                                      m_power)  # particles are just a decoration, 3.5 is here to make particle speed adequate
            p.ApplyLinearImpulse((ox * MAIN_ENGINE_POWER * m_power, oy * MAIN_ENGINE_POWER * m_power), impulse_pos,
                                 True)
            self.lander.ApplyLinearImpulse((-ox * MAIN_ENGINE_POWER * m_power, -oy * MAIN_ENGINE_POWER * m_power),
                                           impulse_pos, True)

        s_power = 0.0
        if (self.continuous and np.abs(action[1]) > 0.5) or (not self.continuous and action in [1, 3]):
            # Orientation engines
            if self.continuous:
                direction = np.sign(action[1])
                s_power = np.clip(np.abs(action[1]), 0.5, 1.0)
                assert s_power >= 0.5 and s_power <= 1.0
            else:
                direction = action - 2
                s_power = 1.0
            ox = tip[0] * dispersion[0] + side[0] * (3 * dispersion[1] + direction * SIDE_ENGINE_AWAY / SCALE)
            oy = -tip[1] * dispersion[0] - side[1] * (3 * dispersion[1] + direction * SIDE_ENGINE_AWAY / SCALE)
            impulse_pos = (self.lander.position[0] + ox - tip[0] * 17 / SCALE,
                           self.lander.position[1] + oy + tip[1] * SIDE_ENGINE_HEIGHT / SCALE)
            p = self._create_particle(0.7, impulse_pos[0], impulse_pos[1], s_power)
            p.ApplyLinearImpulse((ox * SIDE_ENGINE_POWER * s_power, oy * SIDE_ENGINE_POWER * s_power), impulse_pos,
                                 True)
            self.lander.ApplyLinearImpulse((-ox * SIDE_ENGINE_POWER * s_power, -oy * SIDE_ENGINE_POWER * s_power),
                                           impulse_pos, True)

        self.world.Step(1.0 / FPS, 6 * 30, 2 * 30)

        pos = self.lander.position
        vel = self.lander.linearVelocity
        state = [
            (pos.x - VIEWPORT_W / SCALE / 2) / (VIEWPORT_W / SCALE / 2),
            (pos.y - (self.helipad_y + LEG_DOWN / SCALE)) / (VIEWPORT_W / SCALE / 2),
            vel.x * (VIEWPORT_W / SCALE / 2) / FPS,
            vel.y * (VIEWPORT_H / SCALE / 2) / FPS,
            self.lander.angle,
            20.0 * self.lander.angularVelocity / FPS,
            1.0 if self.legs[0].ground_contact else 0.0,
            1.0 if self.legs[1].ground_contact else 0.0
        ]
        assert len(state) == 8

        reward = 0
        shaping = \
            - 100 * np.sqrt(state[0] * state[0] + state[1] * state[1]) \
            - 100 * np.sqrt(state[2] * state[2] + state[3] * state[3]) \
            - 100 * abs(state[4]) + 10 * state[6] + 10 * state[7]  # And ten points for legs contact, the idea is if you
        # lose contact again after landing, you get negative reward
        if self.prev_shaping is not None:
            reward = shaping - self.prev_shaping
        self.prev_shaping = shaping

        reward -= m_power * 0.30  # less fuel spent is better, about -30 for heurisic landing
        reward -= s_power * 0.03

        done = False
        if self.game_over or abs(state[0]) >= 1.0:
            done = True
            reward = -100
        if not self.lander.awake:
            done = True
            reward = +100
        return np.array(state), reward, done, {}

    def render(self, mode='human'):
        from gym.envs.classic_control import rendering
        if self.viewer is None:
            self.viewer = rendering.Viewer(VIEWPORT_W, VIEWPORT_H)
            self.viewer.set_bounds(0, VIEWPORT_W / SCALE, 0, VIEWPORT_H / SCALE)

        for obj in self.particles:
            obj.ttl -= 0.15
            obj.color1 = (max(0.2, 0.2 + obj.ttl), max(0.2, 0.5 * obj.ttl), max(0.2, 0.5 * obj.ttl))
            obj.color2 = (max(0.2, 0.2 + obj.ttl), max(0.2, 0.5 * obj.ttl), max(0.2, 0.5 * obj.ttl))

        self._clean_particles(False)

        for p in self.sky_polys:
            self.viewer.draw_polygon(p, color=(0, 0, 0))

        for obj in self.particles + self.drawlist:
            for f in obj.fixtures:
                trans = f.body.transform
                if type(f.shape) is circleShape:
                    t = rendering.Transform(translation=trans * f.shape.pos)
                    self.viewer.draw_circle(f.shape.radius, 20, color=obj.color1).add_attr(t)
                    self.viewer.draw_circle(f.shape.radius, 20, color=obj.color2, filled=False, linewidth=2).add_attr(t)
                else:
                    path = [trans * v for v in f.shape.vertices]
                    self.viewer.draw_polygon(path, color=obj.color1)
                    path.append(path[0])
                    self.viewer.draw_polyline(path, color=obj.color2, linewidth=2)

        for x in [self.helipad_x1, self.helipad_x2]:
            flagy1 = self.helipad_y
            flagy2 = flagy1 + 50 / SCALE
            self.viewer.draw_polyline([(x, flagy1), (x, flagy2)], color=(1, 1, 1))
            self.viewer.draw_polygon([(x, flagy2), (x, flagy2 - 10 / SCALE), (x + 25 / SCALE, flagy2 - 5 / SCALE)],
                                     color=(0.8, 0.8, 0))

        return self.viewer.render(return_rgb_array=mode == 'rgb_array')

    def close(self):
        if self.viewer is not None:
            self.viewer.close()
            self.viewer = None


class LunarLanderContinuous(LunarLander):
    continuous = True


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Load the Lunar Lander environment
    env = LunarLander()

    total_rewards = list()

    for i in range(0, 10):
        s = env.reset()

        # Load and initialise the contrll model
        ROWS = 64
        COLS = 64
        CHANNELS = 1
        model = joblib.load('player_state.pkl')

        # Run the game loop
        total_reward = 0
        steps = 0
        while True:

            # Get the model to make a prediction
            a = model.predict_classes(s)
            a = a[0]

            # Step on the game
            s, r, done, info = env.step(a)
            env.render()
            total_reward += r
            if steps % 20 == 0 or done:
                print(["{:+0.2f}".format(x) for x in s])
                print("step {} total_reward {:+0.2f}".format(steps, total_reward))
            steps += 1

            if done:
                total_rewards.append(total_reward)
                break

print("total rewards", total_rewards)
print("average total reward", np.mean(total_rewards))

# Write total rewards to file
f = open("lunarlander_ml_states_rewards.csv", 'w')
wr = csv.writer(f)
for r in total_rewards:
    wr.writerow([r, ])
f.close()
```

When I run the code, an error occurs

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/leejoonsung/PycharmProjects/lunar_lander/lunar_lander_ml_states_player.py", line 406, in <module>
    a = model.predict_classes(s)
AttributeError: 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'predict_classes'
```

Could anyone help me solve the problem

Comment: Use `model.predict(s)` as per [the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.predict)

Comment: Thanks~~ it works

Comment: Another issue occurs ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[ 0.00522947  0.9378773   0.52967393 -0.18241832 -0.00605287 -0.11997908
  0.          0.        ].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample. How can I solve it??

Comment: As the error says, the function is expecting a 2D array as an input. You're just feeding it a single example, you can either use `model.predict(s.reshape(-1, 1))` or `model.predict([s])`

Comment: Thank you so much, problem solved ~